# ModelState keys are inconsistent between MVC and WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

If I use a MVC controller, I get a property name for the key. If I use a WebApi controller, I get  "parameterName.property" as the name of the key.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 12)]
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```

In an MVC controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SomeClass collection)
{
    // ModelState.Keys.ElementAt(0) == "Blah"
}
```

In a WebApiController (passing in some request body like "blah=1")

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(SomeClass someClass1)
{
    // ModelState.Keys.ElementAt(0) == "someClass1.Blah"
}
```

So instead of getting "Blah", which would be consistent with MVC, I'm getting "someClass1.blah". Why is there this inconsistency? Is there a setting I'm missing? Is this a bug in the RC? Both projects were created from scratch in VS2012 RC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually by design. For more details take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx).

Comment: I also had posted this to CodePlex and never got notified of a similar "by design" response. See http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/253

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in RC code to me. However, model binding in Web API is separate from ASP.NET MVC model binding so if you added some custom **MVC** model binding code, it won't apply to Web API controllers. This [good blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/27/disabling-model-binding-on-asp-net-web-apis-beta.aspx) has some good info on the differences between Web API & MVC model binding.